# TabControl with the same controls on each tab

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, tabcontrol

I'd like have the same controls on all pages of `TabControl`.

I have `tabControl` without any `tabPages` in my form. And in the same form I have some controls that I want automatically add to each `tabPage`. And work with them. How can I do that?

I'd like something like this:

```
    public chatForm(string chatID, object conversation)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        createNewTab(chatID, conversation);
    }

    internal void createNewTab(string chatID, object conversation)
    {
        ISIMtabPage newTab = new ISIMtabPage();
        newTab.Text = Converter.getContactName(conversation);
        newTab.Name = chatID;

        newTab.conversation = conversation;

        newTab.avatarBox.Image = new Bitmap("graphics\\anonymousAvatar.png");// how can I work with this control in the selected tab?
```

How can I do that all controls will be automatically in each `tabPage` and how can I work with them?

Comment: I would create a new UserControl an drive it from TabItem. Modify it to my needs and add this control as TabItem to my TabControl.

Comment: I already created my TabPage control. But what with controls what I want in each TabPage?

Comment: Off-topic: That's an unusual place to call `InitializeComponent`. Usually it is called as the first thing in the constructor.

Comment: Don't know what you mean. I've change my code. I'm still encountering problem with controls. Don't know how can I make that they will automatically be in each tabPage and how can I work with them.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this (The code is for a WPF solution, have overlooed the WinForm-Tag. But should work similar.):

MyTabItem.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MyTabItem : TabItem, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region PropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    private string myTitle;
    public string MyTitle
    {
        get { return myTitle; } 
        set 
        {
            myTitle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyTitle");
        }
    }

    private string myContent;
    public string MyContent { 
        get { return myContent; } 
        set 
        { 
            myContent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyContent");
        } 
    }

    #endregion

    public MyTabItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

MyTabItem.xaml

```
<TabItem x:Class="WpfApplication1.MyTabItem"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}">

    <TabItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTitle}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>

    <TabItem.Content>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyContent}" Background="Azure"/>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem.Content>
</TabItem>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var tab = new MyTabItem {MyContent = "Content", MyTitle = "Title"};

    MyTabControl.Items.Add(tab);
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl x:Name="MyTabControl"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Now I have it like this. But how can I do that, on all TabPages will have the same components? And then how can I work with them? I have some buttons in the form where is tabControl. Tab control doesn't have any tab created yet. And controls I want have in all tabPages are in the form. How can I add them to new tabPage and how can I work with them on the exists tabPage?

Comment: You can add the same controls you have in your main view to the MytabItem and fill it with content like I did it with MyTitle and MyContent.

Comment: And what with events? Fxp. button_click event. Should I also add them in to my tabPage?

Comment: This is a WPF/Silverlight solution, not WinForms.

Comment: @sczdavos usually you create a class with all properties you like to work with and share an instance of that in your views. My example is in WPF and not WinForms but it should work similar. I think you should think about your concept, copy&paste controls seams to me the wrong approach.

Comment: I have own class which extends TabPage component. I just add my properties. But I want have on all pages the same components. If I call addMessage method it just add text to `tabPage[id].conversationTextBox.Append(message);` and call something like `tabPage[id].Select()` And if I click on another tab it will show other current conversation. I don't understand and don't know what and how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

> I have own class which extends TabPage component. I just add my properties. But I want have on all pages the same components. If I call addMessage method it just add text to tabPage[id].conversationTextBox.Append(message); [...] And if I click on another tab it will show other current conversation. I don't understand and don't know what and how to do that. – sczdavos

This is because primitive types will passed by value, complex by reference!
I have found this example about reference and value types and hope you can learn from that [1]. After you have read it try this:

> @sczdavos usually you create a class with all properties you like to work with and share an instance of that in your views. [...]

[1] http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32029/Reference-and-Value-Types-in-C